# Валидация строки из одних букв любых языков в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает данное регулярное выражение в js скрипте ???

```
var nameRegExp = /^[\p{L}]{2,14}$/;
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: nameRegExp.test('ыполывпы') => false

Comment: nameRegExp.test('fsdkjgsd') => false

Comment: есть ли какой-то метасимвол, обозначающий "буква любого языка". Просто в java это \p. Тут видимо такого нету

Comment: похоже, что в реализации javascript нет такого. \w в js похоже работает только ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) для поддержки символов unicode

```
var regex = new XRegExp("^[\\p{L}]{2,14}$")
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете данное регулярное выражение в среде, поддерживающее стандарт ECMAScript 2018 и новее (например, последние версии Chrome, Node.js), необходимо добавить модификатор `u`:

```js
var nameRegExp = /^\p{L}{2,14}$/u;
console.log(
    nameRegExp.test("Саша")
);
```

См. [документацию на англ. языке](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-CharacterClassEscape). Вот примерный [список значений](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324149/3832970) `\p`:

```
\p{L}  = \p{Letter}:            любая буква любого языка
\p{Ll} = \p{Lowercase_Letter}:  строчная буква, имеющая заглавный вариант написания 
\p{Lu} = \p{Uppercase_Letter}:  заглавная буква, имеющая строчный вариант написания
\p{Lt} = \p{Titlecase_Letter}:  буква в начале слова, являющаяся единственной заглавной буквой в этом слове
\p{L&} = \p{Cased_Letter}:      буква, имеющая прописной и строчный варианты написания (сочетание Ll, Lu и Lt)
\p{Lm} = \p{Modifier_Letter}:   специальный символ, используемый как буква
\p{Lo} = \p{Other_Letter}:      буква или идеограф, не имеющие заглавных и строчных вариантов 
\p{M}  = \p{Mark}:              символ, используемый только в сочетании с другим символом (например диакритические знаки, умляуты, обрамляющие рамки и т.д.)
\p{Mn} = \p{Non_Spacing_Mark}:  символ, используемый только в сочетании с другим символом без пробела между ними (например диакритические знаки, умляуты и т.д.)
\p{Mc} = \p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}: символ, используемый только в сочетании с другим символом, который занимает отдельное место в строке (гласные знаки во многих восточных языках).
\p{Me} = \p{Enclosing_Mark}:    символ, внутри которого отображается другой сопряжённый с ним символ (круг, квадрат, клавишная рамка и т.д.)
\p{Z}  = \p{Separator}:         любой пробельный или непечатаемый разделитель
\p{Zs} = \p{Space_Separator}:   пробельный символ, занимающий отдельное место в строке
\p{Zl} = \p{Line_Separator}:    разделитель строк `U+2028`
\p{Zp} = \p{Paragraph_Separator}: разделитель абзацев `U+2029`
\p{S}  = \p{Symbol}:            математические символы, символы валют, шрифта Дингбат, символы-рамки и т.д.
\p{Sm} = \p{Math_Symbol}:       любой математический символ
\p{Sc} = \p{Currency_Symbol}:   любой символ валют
\p{Sk} = \p{Modifier_Symbol}:   модифицирующий символ (знак) в качестве самостоятельного символа
\p{So} = \p{Other_Symbol}:      любые символы, не являющиеся математическими, модифицирующими символами и символами валют
\p{N}  = \p{Number}:            любой числовой символ
\p{Nd} = \p{Decimal_Digit_Number}: цифра от 0 до 9, за исключением идеографических языков
\p{Nl} = \p{Letter_Number}:     число, которое выглядит как буква (такие как римские цифры)
\p{No} = \p{Other_Number}:      надстрочная и подстрочная цифра или число, не являющаяся цифрой от 0 до 9 (за исключением чисел в идеографических языках)
\p{P}  = \p{Punctuation}:       любой пунктуационный знак
\p{Pd} = \p{Dash_Punctuation}:  любой знак вроде тире или дефиса
\p{Ps} = \p{Open_Punctuation}:  любые открывающие скобки
\p{Pe} = \p{Close_Punctuation}: любые закрывающие скобки
\p{Pi} = \p{Initial_Punctuation}: любые открывающие кавычки
\p{Pf} = \p{Final_Punctuation}: любые закрывающие кавычки
\p{Pc} = \p{Connector_Punctuation}: пунктуационные знаки, играющие роль соединителей слов, такие как знак подчёркивания
\p{Po} = \p{Other_Punctuation}: любой пунктуационный знак, отличный от тире, скобки, кавычки или соединителя слов.
\p{C}  = \p{Other}:             невидимые управляющие символы и неиспользуемые кодовые точки Юникода
\p{Cc} = \p{Control}:           управляющие символы ASCII или Latin-1: 0x00–0x1F и 0x7F–0x9F
\p{Cf} = \p{Format}:            невидимый индикатор форматирования
\p{Co} = \p{Private_Use}:       любая точка кода Юникода, зарезервированная для частного использования
\p{Cs} = \p{Surrogate}:         одна из половин суррогатной пары в кодировке UTF-16
\p{Cn} = \p{Unassigned}:        любая точка кода Юникода, которой не присвоен символ.
```

Какие символы находит каждый из этих классов можно проверить на странице [Unicode Utilities: UnicodeSet](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BPs%7D&g=&i=).